# Two interfaces in the header file

Tags: objective-c, interface, header-files

I was studying some code and I found something that I didn't quite understand. The .h file of a class has two interfaces defined like this.

```
@interface ClassInterface : UIViewController

// Some properties

@end

@interface ClassInterface (FileOpen)

// Some methods

@end
```

1. What is the purpose of having to interfaces defined in the header file?
2. What is `FileOpen` used for?

Comment: Categories and `#pragma mark` are used interchangeably in Objective-C as delimeters between groups of code in header/implementation files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First one which is mentioned is just declaration part of your properties and method.The purpose of having interface defined in header file is we can communicate with importing other class or accessing properties easily.

```
@interface ClassInterface : UIViewController

// Some properties

@end
```

second one is `category` which is used to extending your class with other methods.The `FileOpen` is used to extending your class with some methods within the classes